# Cannot resolve the symbol mail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I dowenload javax.mail and add it as a library but the android studio cannot resolve the symbol mail, it's like I dont add the library .. how can I solve this?

image :
[image: image of error]

[image: library]

Comment: Have you declared the jar include tag in build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the jar file you also need to mention it in the **build.gradle** file,

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/mail-1.4.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the instructions on the [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android) page?